# WordPress not reading php files and template names in nested folders within the themes folder

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to restructure my WP themes folder by containing php files which were initially in the root of the themes folder into a new folder. However, after doing so, it seems that wordpress is unable to read the pages and the template names.

**Current Structure:**

```
themes/
  api/
    |_admin/
    |_client/
  assets/
    |_css/    
    |_js/
  home.php
  admin_dashboard.php
  client_dashboard.php
```

**New Structure:**

```
themes/
  api/
    |_admin/
    |_client/
  assets/
    |_css/    
    |_js/
  home.php
  views/
    |_admind_dashboard.php
    |_client_dashboard.php
```

I have placed admin_dashboard.php and client_dashboard.php into the views folder inside the themes folder. Please advise how I can solve this issue.

Comment: You need to tell to wordpress that the templates are inside the new folder. if you used the `get_template_part()` to load these files, check that the files are correctly referenced.

Comment: @dwpu Where do I run the `get_template_part()` ?

Comment: I don't know what is the structure of your theme and where you've used your template files. Mine was a suggestion on how to fix if you used that function to load your files.

Comment: @dwpu My template files are in the views folder. See the new structure above

Comment: I mean in term of code, not folders structure.